# Understandings toward Django Tastypie

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I recently went over RESTful API in django and came across Tastypie. I came across the following questions.

1. If we are using hydrate or hydrate_FOO, are we still going to use obj_create? If so, under which condition that we are better-off using obj_create? Whats that used for, any simple scenario explanation?
2. When using hydrate, my understanding is that, we are using hydrate when we only receive POST/Update/Patch request, to transfer data in bundle.data to set correct bundle.obj.Field. Any other cases that we are going to use hydrate?
3. Whats the point of having full_hydrate and hydrate method if we already have hydrate_FOO? Any specific example that the first two are a MUST or better used?
4. Consider the following example:

data from client:

```
{
    "A": "abc",
    "B": "lifeisgood"
}
```

Model File:

```
class A(models.Model):
  Astr = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class B(models.Model):
  Bstr = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class C(models.Model):
  a = models.ForeignKey(A)
  b = models.ManyToManyField(B)
  data = models.DateTime(auto_now=True)
```

The resource file is:

```
class CResource(ModelResource):
  a = fields.ToOneField(AResource, "iamA")
  b = fields.ToManyField(BResource, "iamB")
```

If I get the data from client and it is a POST, what I am currently doing is:
Inside CResource:

```
def hydrate_a(self, bundle):
  bundle.obj.a = A.objects.get(Astr = bundle.data['A'])
  return bundle
def hydrate_b(self, bundle):
  bundle.obj.b = B.objects.filter(Bstr = bundle.data['B'])
  return bundle
```

However, the result I got is:

1. the A resource get into the database and B resource (ManyToMany) does not.
2. It gives me the errors:
   {
   "error_message": "",
   "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n\n  File \"/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_tastypie-0.10.0-py2.6.egg/tastypie/resources.py\", line 195, in wrapper\n    response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_tastypie-0.10.0-py2.6.egg/tastypie/resources.py\", line 426, in dispatch_list\n    return self.dispatch('list', request, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_tastypie-0.10.0-py2.6.egg/tastypie/resources.py\", line 458, in dispatch\n    response = method(request, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_tastypie-0.10.0-py2.6.egg/tastypie/resources.py\", line 1320, in post_list\n    updated_bundle = self.obj_create(bundle, **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))\n\n  File \"/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_tastypie-0.10.0-py2.6.egg/tastypie/resources.py\", line 2084, in obj_create\n    return self.save(bundle)\n\n  File \"/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_tastypie-0.10.0-py2.6.egg/tastypie/resources.py\", line 2235, in save\n    self.save_m2m(m2m_bundle)\n\n  File \"/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_tastypie-0.10.0-py2.6.egg/tastypie/resources.py\", line 2326, in save_m2m\n    related_mngr = getattr(bundle.obj, field_object.attribute)\n\n  File \"/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py\", line 279, in **get**\n    raise self.related.model.DoesNotExist\n\nDoesNotExist\n"
   }

Any idea why this is not correct? What would be the suggested way to save a foreignkey or manytomany related data when do a POST, from the data given in front end.

Many thanks!
-leo

Comment: Does your `B` model with passed `BStr` exist?

Comment: Yes, It is manually put into the database before I make a POST to C model